# Having problems in validation of combobox using PHP.

Tags: php

I am trying to perform validation using PHP. I have some problem to validate Combobox control with a PHP. Here is the code I have:

```
<select  >
<option value"gender">Gender</option> 
                <option value="male">Male </option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
I want validation in such a way that
If( Gender)
{
  Please select Gender;
}else
{
 Gender is selected;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML side example ,

```
<form action="validation.php" method="GET">
 <select name="gender_select">
  <option value"gender">Gender</option> 
  <option value="male">Male </option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

For PHP side example ( validation.php ),

```
<?php

if($_GET['gender_select'] == "gender"){
  echo "Please select a gender";
}else{
  echo "You're ".$_GET['gender_select'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate the values beside checking that if the user selected one, you can use the following method:

```
$good_values = array('male', 'female', 'other');
if (false === in_array(strtolower($_POST['gender']), $good_values)) {
   echo 'Please select a valid gender.';
else
   echo 'You have selected ' . $_POST['gender'];
```

There is nothing wrong with your HTML code.